# selenium Unable to scrape a table

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm unable to scrape the table from https://solanabeach.io/validators. For some reason, I can't access it using the following code snippet. Does anyone have an idea why I'm unable to scrape the table?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

driver.get(f"https://solanabeach.io/validators")


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
api = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*").get_attribute("outerHTML"), 'html.parser')


table = api.findAll('tbody')

print(table)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use BeautifulSoup here. You can simply use selenium methods.

```
import re
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "chrome driver path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

url = 'https://solanabeach.io/validators'

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'ShowValidatorsButton')]")))

showbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'ShowValidatorsButton')]")
showbutton.click()

sleep(10)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-bordered maintable "
                                                "table-striped-even']//tbody/tr")))
columnHeader = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-bordered maintable "
                                             "table-striped-even']//thead")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(re.sub(r"\s+", '|', columnHeader.text.strip()))
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
textInPage = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-bordered maintable "
                                            "table-striped-even']//tbody/tr")
for element in textInPage:
    print(element.text)
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#|VALIDATOR|STAKE|CUMULATIVE|STAKE|COMMISSION|LAST|VOTE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
Chorus One
1.7.14
15,017,730(29319)
3.78 %
3.8 %
8 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2
Everstake
1.8.2
14,657,551(110561)
3.69 %
7.5 %
7 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3
Certus One
1.7.14
11,346,746(15086)
2.86 %
10.3 %
10 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4
Staking Facilities
1.7.14
8,949,137(3657)
2.25 %
12.6 %
8 %
106,531,467
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
5
Bison Trails
1.7.15
7,487,862(2830)
1.89 %
14.5 %
8 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6
DokiaCapital
1.7.14
7,051,193(2478)
1.78 %
16.2 %
5 %
106,531,469
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7
Kraken
1.7.14
6,671,025(105)
1.68 %
17.9 %
100 %
106,531,452
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8
EVw8...3DvU
1.7.15
6,600,000(4)
1.66 %
19.6 %
100 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9
47e2...GueY
1.8.2
6,536,593(541)
1.65 %
21.2 %
8 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10
4khY...eP5A
1.7.15
5,799,900(1)
1.46 %
22.7 %
100 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11
0% Fee to 2022  | melea.xyz One ◎
1.8.2
5,560,661(6157)
1.40 %
24.1 %
0 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12
Shinobi Systems  stakeview.app
1.8.2
5,232,571(8695)
1.32 %
25.4 %
2 %
106,531,468
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And so on.

Comment: thanks @QualityMatters, do you know how to get the first 20 rows by chance? I know there is a button, but I'm struggling to find it

Comment: Updated answer. I clicked on the show validation button first and now it's printing from 1 to the last element.

Comment: @RexG Accept the answer if it solves your question